# Url.RouteUrl returns null, MVC5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have the following `RouteConfig`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "CompareDevicesByPage",
    "ComparedDevices/{id}/{sortingType}/{sortingDirection}/{searchText}/{page}",
    new { controller = "Compare", action = "Page", id = UrlParameter.Optional, sortingType = UrlParameter.Optional, sortingDirection = UrlParameter.Optional, searchText = UrlParameter.Optional, page = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "ManufacturerDevices",
    "Manufacturer/{objectName}/{id}/{title}/{sortingType}/{sortingDirection}/{searchText}/{page}",
    new { controller = "Manufacturer", action = "Devices", title = UrlParameter.Optional, page = UrlParameter.Optional, sortingType = UrlParameter.Optional, sortingDirection = UrlParameter.Optional, searchText = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Whenever I use `Url.RouteUrl` it returns null.

```
Url.RouteUrl("CompareDevicesByPage", new { id = 0, page = 1, sortingType = (short)DevicesSortingEnum.Popular, sortingDirection = (int)SortDirection.Descending, searchText = "" })
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem,
I have to change map routes to the following:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "CompareDevicesByPage",
    "ComparedDevices/{id}/{sortingType}/{sortingDirection}/{page}/{searchText}",
    new { controller = "Compare", action = "Page", id = UrlParameter.Optional, sortingType = UrlParameter.Optional, sortingDirection = UrlParameter.Optional, searchText = UrlParameter.Optional, page = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "ManufacturerDevices",
    "Manufacturer/{objectName}/{id}/{title}/{sortingType}/{sortingDirection}/{page}/{searchText}",
    new { controller = "Manufacturer", action = "Devices", title = UrlParameter.Optional, page = UrlParameter.Optional, sortingType = UrlParameter.Optional, sortingDirection = UrlParameter.Optional, searchText = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```